# Pascal: Finding a last row in an array with specific contents/criteria

Tags: arrays, pascal

There is a Two-Dimensional Array of integers with 'm' rows and 'n' columns. Find the number of the last row in which all the elements are odd numbers.

I'm stuggling in the last part in which I have to find the exact number of the last row which contains only odd numbers.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Loop for each row. Every time you find a row that has all odd numbers, make note of the row number. When you're done looping, the last row number you made note of is the right one. You'll need to take care of the case where none of the rows meets the criteria as well.

Comment: @lurker Or start from the last row. Then you can stop on first encounter.

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i:=m downto 1 do begin
  odd:=true;
  for j:=1 to n do begin
     if a[i][j] mod 2=0 then odd:=false;
   end;
   if odd then begin
     writeln(i);
     break;
   end;
 end;
```